# What tool I can use to map short-reads sequences to reference genome and get specific mapped size

Tags: sequence-alignment, snp, read-mapping

I have about 300 90-bp sequences which I would like to map to a reference genome to make it longer to a 300bp sequence, wherein the 90bp is at the middle.

Anyone knows what bioinformatics tool I can use for this? Thank you!

*Actual scenario:*
The SNP sequences are from a SNP panel data (90bp sequence, SNP is at the middle). We would like to extend the sequence to 300bp, retaining the SNP at the middle so we can make a sequence capture panel of the SNP.

Comment: You mean the target capture panel of SNP markers?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @envs_h_gang_5 I'm actually not very familiar, but something like 'genotyping by sequencing' kind of panel.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a SNP panel then you have the coordinates on the genome. You can use tools such as [bedtools slop](https://bedtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/tools/slop.html) to expand the coordinates to the desired length and then extract those regions from the target genome using [bedtools getfasta](https://bedtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/tools/getfasta.html).

Comment: Thank you! That's very helpful. The dilemma, however, is we'd like to extract the 300bp sequences from a different genome, and not from the reference genome of the SNP panel, therefore the coordinates on the SNP panel will not be exactly on our genome.

Comment: Then you need liftover https://genome.ucsc.edu/cgi-bin/hgLiftOver
I don't know if the genomes you're working on have mapping files though.